# Laravel foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed I have searched and cannot find the answer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-migrations

```php
class CreateMediaTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_posts');
            $table->char('type', 1); //P: photo or V: video
            $table->string('file');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('id_posts')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->foreign('id_users')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

and my createprofilemigration

```
/**
 * @author Alex Madsen
 * 
 * @date November 6, 2018
 */ 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_users')->unique();
            $table->string('handle')->unique(); 
            $table->string('icon')->default('https://i.redd.it/130am13nj6201.png'); 
            $table->string('profile_image')->nullable(); 
            $table->string('description')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_profiles');
    }
}
```

**Keeps throwing these errors, What am I missing? Mind you I am new to this, Trying to learn with youtube and stackoverflow on my off time. Not sure which way to go. I have looked on the forums and tried              $table->foreign('id_posts')->references('id')->on('posts'); But it didn't fix the issue.**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ci`.`media` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter t
able `media` add constraint `media_id_posts_foreign` foreign key (`id_posts`) references `posts` (`id`))

  at C:\xampp6\htdocs\lol\simple_social_network_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
```

```php
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('subreddit_id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_posts');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('id_users')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('subreddit_id')->references('id')->on('id_posts');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your `posts` migration code to ?

Comment: fixed above sorry first post.

Comment: in your `media` migration edit your `posts_id` to `unsignedInteger` to be like this `$table->unsignedInteger('id_posts');`

Answer (score 2):

When using foreign keys types should be exactly the same.

You create:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_posts');
```

so it's unsigned big integer, but probably in `posts` table instead of `bigIncrements` you use just `increments` for `id` column and that's why you are getting this error.

So quite possible instead of:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_posts');
```

you should use

```
$table->unsignedInteger('id_posts');
```

or as alternative solution use

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

in `posts` migration

Comment: @Insomniakinn Yes, so in answer you have solution what you should change

Comment: `$table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_posts');
            $table->char('type', 1); //P: photo or V: video
            $table->string('file');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('id_posts')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->foreign('id_users')->references('id')->on('users');` It's still throwing the same error. Granted I am new to coding, learning on my days off so I am sure user error.

Comment: @Insomniakinn Are you sure error is the same? You should make only change in single file, not in both and it should work

Comment: I went ahead and uploaded code to git, Not sure if having the big picture helps or not. https://github.com/Wildindfw/mylaraveltest

Answer (score 0):

In your `posts` migration, you made your `id` with `increments`
that is mean that it takes

```
unsigned integer auto_increment
```

but in your migration of `media` file, you create a `posts_id` with `unsignedBigInteger`

so there's two way to fix that choose only one

1. edit your `id` in `posts` migration to be `bigincrements`
2. edit your `posts_id` in 'media' migration to `unsignedIntegere`